# Is it possible to write a text below thé cursor's position

Tags: text, position, pdfkit

```
doc.text("msg", x, y);
```

writes `msg` below the position (x, y).

How to write it above this position?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use doc.text("msg", x, y-100), or something similar to accomplish this?

You already have the x, and y coordinates. Just make adjustments to always modify this number as needed when writing text.

Answer (score 0):

Thank-you Anon, but I needed a generic solution.

I have found yesterday a solution :

in the file pdfkit.js, in the "_fragment: fonction (...)", replace the line

y = this.page.height - y - ( this._font.ascender / 1000 * this._fontSize );

by

y = this.page.height - y;

This way it works all the time; even if a transformation matrix is applied to the text.

@+

Answer (score 0):

Use the baseline option

```
doc.text("msg", x, y, { baseline:"bottom" })
```

For baseline, PdfKit supports sames values as [Canvas textBaseLine](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_textbaseline.asp). The default for baseline is 'top'.